# How to post on linkedin group via API or email?

Tags: linkedin-api

I want know like is it possible to post on linkedin groups using PHP Scripts? To make it more clear, we can post on yahoo groups by just sending an email at my group email address. Is there any possibility to do this on Linkedin group? Please help me?

Answer (score 0):

A few methods to post to LinkedIn:

1. Use IFTTT.com; you can set up a Recipe to take an email and send it to linkedIn
2. Use buffer in concert with IFFF to send posts to Linkedin
3. To post to a Linkedin Company Page: Use Hootsuite in concert with buffer/ifttt to post from an RSS feed or from an email